# Arduino + PWM + LED Buck Regulator / Flashing not smooth

Tags: arduino, led

I am trying to use an Arduino + PWM to control a 100w LED using a Sure Electronics 300-3000ma buck regular - [Product Here](http://store3.sure-electronics.com/ps-sp12153)

The chip being used is LM3409

[image: 300-3000mA Buck Regulator LED Driver for 1-100W High Power LED]

The buck regulator is powwered by an external 36v suppply to VCC + GND, and a 100W led is connected to the LED +/-.

This configuration is working fine without PWM but I can not understand how to control it with PWM from an Arduino without flicker.

The arduino is connected to to a 4n35 Optocoupler.

The Arduino Digital Pin 2 is controlled (AnalogWrite) after reading the value of a Potentiometer (0-1024 mapped to 0-255) and is connected via a 200 Ohm Register to Pin 1 of the Optocoupler. Pin 2 of the optocouler is connected to the arduino ground.

```
int led = 2;           // the PWM pin the LED is attached to
int last = 0;
// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // declare pin 9 to be an output:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
   int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
   sensorValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
   if (sensorValue != last)
  {
    last = sensorValue;

    analogWrite(led, sensorValue);
    Serial.println(sensorValue);
  }
}
```

The LED buck device says that the EN pin - PWM terminal when applied with ground or suspended, full amount of current will be output and when connected with +5v or VIN, output current will be 0.

I have tested this, if I connect the 36v from the LED power supply to the EN pin the LED goes out. If I connect to ground or leave floating it runs at 100%

I do not know how to connect the other side of the Optocouler to the EN PIN properly.

I have connected pin 4 of the optocoupler (EMITTER) to the EN PIN, and connected pin 5 (COLLECTor) of the optocoupler to 36V from the VCC on the buck regulator.

This seems to work as it does go up and down in relation to changing the potentiometer.

- 0 from analogWrite on the arduino and the LED is running at 100%\
- 128 from analogWrite on the arduino and the LED is running at 50%
- 255 from analogWrite on the arduino and the LED is running at 0%

But it is not a constant brightness, it is flashing terribly and not usable.

Any help appreciated as I do not know how to move on with this.

[image: Actual Layout]

Comment: I’m not a programmer, but is _delay(100)_ 100 ms worth of delay, i.e. 10 Hz? Then yes, it will flicker terribly.

Comment: The delay is not needed as the arduino analogWrite() creates the PWM signal.  I removed it from the code above.

Comment: I removed the buck regulator and use a simple LED and a resister going to ground and it seems to dim perfectly.

I do not understand how the dimming is supposed to work on this driver. Also using another simple driver with separate PWM + GND worked perfectly. I just need help with these Sure Electronics drivers.

Comment: Show circuit diagram.

Comment: I added the components I am using to the main question.

Comment: Does the buck converter start a new soft start sequence each time EN goes high or is it meant for PWM-dimming?

Comment: From the data sheet: Logic level enable and PWM dimming. Apply a voltage >1.74 V to enable device, a PWM signal to dim, or a voltage < 0.5 V for low-power shutdown.

Comment: The enable pin (EN) is a TTL compatible input for PWM dimming of the LED. A logic low (below 0.5V) at EN will disable the internal driver and shut off the current flow to the LED array. While the EN pin is in a logic low state the support circuitry (driver, bandgap, VCC regulator) remains active to minimize the time needed to turn the LED array back on when the EN pin sees a logic high (above 1.74 V).

Comment: Right, that sounds correct. You need to break out your oscilloscope to trace the problem.

Comment: What sounds correct?

Do you know based on the data sheet voltages what the PWM min/max voltages should be?

Answer (score 1):

OK with the help of a colleage at my work I have now got it working.

[image: Correct Solution for Optocoupler]

[image: My Correct Solution]

Comment: Ah! A missing pull-up. I would not pull up to 36 V unless I knew that the EN pin was made for it. It might be over the rating for the optocoupler too.

Comment: The EN pin is rated at 45V, and the 4N35 is rated at 70V so no problem there.

LM3409 - VIN, EN, UVLO to GND - 45V
4n35 - Collector emitter breakdown voltage VCEO 70 V